# Blueimp Problems with image resize

Tags: blueimp

I have developed a website in php using codeigniter with blueimp to upload images and it is working perfectly, but image resize doesn't work. Follow main.js

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'admin/upload/do_upload'
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
        dataType: 'json',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
        imageMaxWidth: 800,
        imageMaxHeight: 800,
        imageCrop: true // Force cropped images
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/upload/do_upload',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
} else {
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
}
```

});

In my View you have the following JS imported:

```
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/tmpl.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/load-image.all.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/canvas-to-blob.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/query.blueimp-gallery.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-image.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('libs/js/fileupload/main.js') ?>"></script>
```

I am currently using XAMPP for testing, I saw here in the forum that I should change `if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io')` to `if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {`But it still doesn't work.

Every time I upload it it drops in ELSE and not in the IF where the resize part is. What would be the mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: use `console.log(window.location.hostname)` in else condition.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to change to localhost and the url to admin/upload/do_upload that way the images were resized. But now the thumbnails no longer appear on the screen, where do I need to configure them yet? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Debugging the Image upload

use `console.log(window.location.hostname)` in else condition.

Check the path of one image by **directly accessing the IMAGE Url** in your browser.

Then check thumbnail image path on your website using **ISPECT element** in your browser.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @user2733757 is it helpfull ??